# Properties of distribuition function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $m(\{|f| > \lambda\}) \to 0$ whenever $\lambda \to \infty$ and let
>   $$f^{\ast}(t) = \inf\{\lambda \mid m(\{|f| > \lambda\}) \leq t\},\quad t \geq0.$$
>   Prove that
>
> (i) $f$ is nonincreasing and right-continuous.
>
> (ii) If $0<\eta<m(\{|f|>\lambda\}) < \infty$, then
>   $$f^{\ast}(m(\{|f|>\lambda\})) \leq \lambda < f^{\ast}(m(\{|f|>\lambda\}) - \eta).$$
>
> (iii) If $f^{\ast}$ is continuous at $t = m(\{|f|>\lambda\})$, then $f^{\ast}(m(\{|f|>\lambda\})) = \lambda$.
>
> (iv) $f$ and $f^{\ast}$ are equimeasurable.

- $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I proved the items (i) and (iv). In the item (ii), I proved the first inequality. I need help with the second inequality of item (ii) and item (iii). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $S_{\lambda}:=\{|f|>\lambda\}$.

(ii):

$$f^*(m(S_{\lambda}))) = \mbox{inf}\{\tau|\ m(S_{\tau})\leq m(S_{\lambda})\}\leq\lambda.$$

$$f(m(S_{\lambda})-\eta)=\mbox{inf}\{\tau|\ m(S_{\tau})\leq m(S_{\lambda})-\eta\},$$

Clearly the minimizer $\tau^*= \mbox{inf}\{\tau|m(S_\tau)\leq m(S_\lambda)-\eta\}$ above must satisfy $\tau^*>\lambda$, as $m(S_\tau)$ is monotonically decreasing in $\tau$, e.g. $m(S_\tau)\geq m(S_\lambda)$ whenever $\tau<\lambda$. .

(iii):

$$f^*(t)=f^*(m(S_{\lambda}))\leq \lambda,$$

by (ii). On the other hand for $\eta$ satisfying (ii),

$$\lambda<f^*(m(S_{\lambda})-\eta)$$

So take the limit of $\eta\rightarrow 0^+$. It follows that $\lambda\leq f(m(S_{\lambda}))$, so $\lambda \leq f(t) \leq \lambda$, i.e. $f(t)=\lambda$.

Comment: In the item (ii), who is $\tau^{\ast}$?

Comment: $\tau^*= \mbox{inf}\{\tau|m(S_\tau)\leq m(S_\lambda)-\eta\}$, i.e. the minimizer. Edited for clarity.